How to send failed messages from a WSO2 ESB message processor to a Dead Letter Channel (DLC)?
I am using WSO2 ESB (MI) with ActiveMQ Classic for message processing. I have a message processor configured to process some incoming messages, and I would like to set up a Dead Letter Channel (DLC) to handle messages that fail to be processed by the message processor. Currently, after failing max attempts the message processor will be deactivated.
How can I configure the message processor to send failed messages to a Dead Letter Queue (DLQ) for further analysis or manual processing?
I have already tried configuring the message processor with the deadLetterQueue parameter set to the DLQ name, but the failed messages are not being moved to the DLQ as expected.

You can use following with ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor
<parameter name="message.processor.failMessagesStore">dlq-store</parameter>

this will backup forward messages that fail to reach the backend.
Specifying a backup message store allows the message processor to continue processing the next message instead of deactivating in case a message fails to be delivered to the backend

Thanks for the answer, but this is just another message store right, I know we can use this as a DLQ, but this is not exactly a DLQ.

With current MI architecture we can't use the exact ActiveMQ.DLQ with message processors, but by setting up a separate queue, we can achieve similar functionality using message processors as given above.
But you could use listener proxy or inbound as given below instead of message processor
https://www.yenlo.com/blogs/rollout-activemq-and-its-retry-mechanism-in-wso2/
